# Set Selected Date to TimePicker wpf (TimePickers inside DataTemplate)

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker

I want Selected Date for my TimePicker. When I select specific date from calendar which present in my View Window, that date should assign to Timepicker.

Xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
   <xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" Value="{Binding StartTime, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
   <xctk:TimePicker Name="EndPicker" Value="{Binding EndTime, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Below property updates Time for TimePicker but sets Today's Date. I want selected Date which I select at runtime.

```
private DateTime _started_at;
private DateTime _ended_at;

public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _started_at;
        }
        set
        {
            _started_at = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime EndTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _ended_at;
        }
        set
        {
            _ended_at = value;
        }
    }
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are binding to properties that don't exist. Change your bindings from StartValue and EndValue to StartTime and EndTime.

TimePicker:

```
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
   <xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" Value="{Binding StartTime, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
   <xctk:TimePicker Name="EndPicker" Value="{Binding EndTime, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

*EDIT* Did some google-jerking and realized that you don't have any notification of property changed. Try adding INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and raising OnPropertyChanged events to see if that clears it up. [example with onPropertyChanged](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ceb602bb-3261-467a-b5d7-33827853ebf6/twoway-databinding-of-datepicker)

Comment: Added some info and link to another idea.

Comment: I tried using INotifyPropertyChanged interface. But still not set to selected date.

Comment: Just to verify, you ARE setting some DataSource or ItemsSource somewhere in that code to bind to your TimePicker class, yes?

Comment: TimePickers are directly binded with StartTime and EndTime only. I've not used any ItemSource or DataSource for it.

Comment: OK. You need to set some binding source on the control that contains your DataTemplate. Somehow, you have to specify that the BindingSource for the control is an instance of your TimePicker class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35451/discussion-between-joe-brunscheon-and-user2622971)